# Small question about accuracy and precision

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

Let's say I have a law like this,
$$D=\frac{c}{r}$$
where $c$ is a constant, $r$ a distance in meter. my measures of $r$ are [$0.02m$, $0.01m$], then $<r>=0.015m$ and $\delta r = \pm 0.005m$. So now if I want to calculate $D+\delta D$ should I use $+\delta r$ or $- \delta r$ in my equation?

because if I use $+\delta r$ I get a smaller value than if I use $-\delta  r$ since $r$ divide $c$

edit: in my real problem I have a lot of data, all is fine when I use the minus delta. I just want to be sure...

Comment: You may be interested in the LaTeX commands `\langle` and `\rangle` to produce $\langle r\rangle$, and the proper way `$1\:\mathrm{m}$` to produce $1\:\mathrm{m}$.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty thx for that comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to propagate uncertainties is, in this case,
$$
\delta D = \left|\frac{\partial D}{\partial r}\right|\delta r=\frac{c\, \delta r}{r^2},
$$
where $\delta r$ is a positive quantity. Then $\delta D>0$ gives you half the width of your uncertainty interval in $D$.

Comment: thx, it's a bit more complex than what I did... I have to fix my calculus...